# java bitwise operators and the equal character; compound operators

Tags: java, operators, bit-manipulation, compound-operator

I'm a bit confused:

```
long v = 0;
v <<= 8; 
v |= 230;
```

I know << is the signed left shift operator and | Bitwise the inclusive OR but I'm confused to what the equals does?

So fist v is 0. So << doesn't have any effect? Then it equals 1000
but what happens then?

edit: I've edited the title so others might better find this question: added "compound operators"

Comment: It has an effect. `v = v << 8` and then `v = v | 230`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are somewhat like `+=`.

For example `x+=3` means add 3 to x; store to x.

```
v <<= 8;
```

left-shifts v 8 bits, and stores to v, functionally equivalent to `v=v << 8`.

```
v |= 230;
```

does a bitwise OR with 230 and stores back to v, equivalent to `v=v | 230`.

Now, due to performance constraints and optimizations this operation may be done *in place* at a low level.

Comment: @Thomas No problem. Please accept the answer that helped you most using the checkmark next to it.

Comment: I have to wait a few minutes before I can; but I will :)

Comment: After the execution `v=v | 230` what will be the `v` value ??

Comment: @sureshatta Just try it and see. It depends on the original `v` value

Answer (score 5):

They're *compound* operators, like `+=` and `-=` are. They do the operation, and then assign the result back to `v`.

Basically:

```
v <<= 8;
```

is in effect

```
v = v << 8;
```

And similarly

```
v |= 230;
```

is in effect

```
v = v | 230;
```

You can see the parallel with `+=` and `-=`:

```
v += 1;
```

is effectively

```
v = v + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this:

```
v <<= 8; 
v |= 230;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
v = v << 8; 
v = v | 230;
```